# Basis of a Null space of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I don't know when should I use echelon form or reduced row echelon form?

I used echelon form for $\alpha\neq0$ and got equations:

[image]

What next? and what's the difference between $\alpha\neq0$ and $\alpha=0$?

Comment: If you use reduced row echelon form it's easier to get the basis for the null space. And if $\alpha=0$ just put those in (so the last row then starts with all zeros) and re-do the row reduced echelon form, it becomes a different problem.

Comment: @coffeemath Could you please show some steps?

Comment: user102148 I just put an "answer" with steps shown to get null spaces, but did not show the reduced form reductions, as it seems you know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to row reduced form with $\alpha \neq 0$ you get three equations
$$x+17/9t=0, \\ y+ 2/9t = 0, \\ z + 5/9t=0.$$
So the solution is $(x,y,z,t)=t(-17/9,-2/9,-5/9,1)$ and then the single vector after the factor $t$ is the basis of the (one dimensional) null space.

On the other hand if $\alpha = 0$ (so that the last row of starting matrix is all zeroes), on going to row reduced form there are only two equations
$$x - 23/2z - 9/2 t=0, \\ y -4z - 2 t=0,$$
with solution $(x,y,z,t)=z(23/2,4,1,0)+t(9/2,2,0,1),$ so this time the null space is two dimensional, with basis given by the vector after the factor $z$ and the vector after the factor $t$.

In either case you can make the basis look "nicer" by multiplying each basis vector by something to clear the denominators.

Answer (score 2):

When finding a basis for the Null Space of a matrix the number of free variables is equal to the number of vectors in a basis for that matrix.

When finding the Null Space, ALWAYS reduce to Reduced Row Echelon Form (RREF). From There, it is just finding the solution to Ax = 0. where x and zero are vectors.

A popular way to solve this quickly is to use the "padding trick."

Padding Trick Algorithm:
1) Put your matrix in RREF.
2) Kill all zero rows.
3) Add a row for each free variable
These added rows will be zero rows with the exception of "-1"s along the main diagonal.
4) Circle your columns with the "-1"s along the main diagonal in them.]
5) These are the vectors that will form a basis for the Null Space of your matrix.

EDIT:  The alpha = 0 and alpha does not equal zero just means you will be finding two null spaces.  One for each case. I believe when alpha does not equal zero your final answer will be implicit.